# scala for if loop beginner example

Tags: scala, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I am new to scala and I'm not sure what is the best way to convert a for/if loop I have written in c++ into scala.  I'm working on translating my entire document so if someone could give me a first step that would be helpful!

suppose `array1`, `array2`, `array3` and `array4` are all initialised and are of size `n-1`

The code is

```
 n=10
 k=4

for(i=0,i<n,i++) {
  if (array1(i) > k){
    array2(i)=0
  }
  else if (array1(i)>-k) { 
    if (array3(i)>0) {
      array2(i)=1
      array4(i)=2
    }
    else {
      array2(i)=2
      array4(i)=0
    }
  else {
    array2(i)=3
    array4(i)=4
  }
}
```

Comment: Your example does not represent itself very well in FP world. It raises a lot of questions. In Scala arrays are rarely used. Also why do you want 4 arrays if you can have an array of some value that brings more context? In real world each of your array means something and you can use that, creating a data structure for it. Without that there is no reason to overcomplicate, and you will still have the same loop and access your array by index, and with that you stay in any other world, but not FP world

Answer (score 3):

In your case something like

```
for( n <- 0 until 10){
...
}
```

would be the simplest loop. *Until* is exclusive the end. If you want to loop inclusive the end, you use *to* instead of *until*. You might also want to consider using pattern matching instead of your nested if/elses.
Here are also some links the cover the basics of Scala in an interactive way:
http://scalatutorials.com/

http://scala-exercises.47deg.com/

Comment: But is there any other neater way to do it with filter/case matching?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to work with many Arrays of the same size in a convenient (almost Scala-like) manner:

The first tip is the use of transpose to "pair" elements of the same index together.

```
val tmp = Array(Array(1,2), Array(3,4), Array(5,6)).transpose
> tmp: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 3, 5), Array(2, 4, 6))
```

Then we can even use pattern matching to have an easy way to refer to the corresponding elements (x,y,z, ...):

```
for(Array(x,y,z) <- tmp) yield x + 2y + z/2 
> Array[Int] = Array(9, 13)
```

I am not going to replicate the entire logic, but this should suffice for you to re-write your logic in this style:

Using the REPL:

```
scala> val a1 = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
a1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val a2 = Array(11,21,31,41,51)
a2: Array[Int] = Array(11, 21, 31, 41, 51)

scala> val a3 = Array(22,22,32,42,52)
a3: Array[Int] = Array(22, 22, 32, 42, 52)

scala> val a4 = Array(9,8,7,6,4)
a4: Array[Int] = Array(9, 8, 7, 6, 4)

// zipWithIndex gives us access to "i" as we iterate over the array
scala> val toIterate = Array(a1,a2,a3,a4).transpose.zipWithIndex
toIterate: Array[(Array[Int], Int)] = Array((Array(1, 11, 22, 9),0), (Array(2, 21, 22, 8),1), (Array(3, 31, 32, 7),2), (Array(4, 41, 42, 6),3), (Array(5, 51, 52, 4),4))

for( j <- toIterate ) {
   j match {
      case (Array(e1,e2,e3,e4),i) if e1 > 4 => a1(i) = 3
      // add more cases here ... 
      case (_,i) => a3(i)=3; a4(i) = 4
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scala-ish transliteration of your algorithm, but really without context it's difficult to say what you're trying to achieve, as @Archeg says.

Initialise stuff

```
val n = 10
val k = 4 
val input1 = new Array[Int](n)
val input3 = new Array[Int](n)
```

(renaming the arrays to better represent what they're used for)
We go through the arrays in lockstep, so zip them together to form pairs of elements of the same index, and go through that:

```
 val res =   {for ((a, b) <- input1 zip input3)
```

Each time, we produce (`"yield"`) one pair for the output of that index too

```
yield {
if (a > k) {
  (0, 0)    // here we assume a value for array4. Not clear what is intended
} else if (a > -k) {
  if (b > 0) {
    (1, 2)
  } else {
    (2, 0)
  }
} else {
  (3, 4)
}
```

So now we have one array of pairs of result elements. Unzip that to two arrays of the first and second elements of the pairs

```
val (array2, array4) = res.unzip
```

So, is this better? It doesn't use indexes explicitly, so it's less likely to have off-by-one errors, or to use the wrong index accidentally.  But whether it's a clearer expression of your intent depends on what your code was supposed to be doing. If we knew what it meant, there are probably clearer ways of doing it.